# ip route src not working

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ip, routes

1I need to use several IPs on interface in Linux, and switch it, but it's not working.
for example:

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:2b:34:33:80:65  
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::922b:34ff:fe33:8065/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13220652 errors:0 dropped:32864 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8296620 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:16166162509 (16.1 GB)  TX bytes:2186645852 (2.1 GB)
          Interrupt:48 

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:2b:34:33:80:65  
          inet addr:192.168.1.99  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              Interrupt:48 

lo        Link encap:Локальная петля (Loopback)  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:276685 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:276685 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:21387439 (21.3 MB)  TX bytes:21387439 (21.3 MB)

# ip route
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  scope link  src 192.168.1.99 

# ping 192.168.1.50
PING 192.168.1.50 (192.168.1.50) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.50: icmp_req=1 ttl=255 time=1.21 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.50: icmp_req=2 ttl=255 time=1.07 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.50: icmp_req=3 ttl=255 time=1.05 ms
```

and then i use Curl

```
# curl 192.168.1.50
```

and tcpdump:

```
13:24:02.009094 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.50: ICMP echo request, id 8919, seq 347, length 64
E..T..@.@..%.......2...s"..[...P....q#...................... !"#$%&'()*+,-./01234567
13:24:02.010087 IP 192.168.1.50 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo reply, id 8919, seq 347, length 64
E..T...........2.......s"..[...P....q#...................... !"#$%&'()*+,-./01234567
13:43:40.006264 IP 192.168.1.1.48275 > 192.168.1.50.80: Flags [S], seq 3496592766, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 15698502 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<O8@.@.h........2...P.i.~......9............
...F........
13:43:40.007663 IP 192.168.1.50.80 > 192.168.1.1.48275: Flags [S.], seq 3006420619, ack 3496592767, win 5792, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 151247914 ecr 15698502,nop,wscale 0], length 0
E..<..@.@..8...2.....P...2V..i.................
    ..*...F....
```

and source ip is still 192.168.1.1, what am i doing wrong?

UPD: BTW, just tryed same thing on Ubuntu 10.04 with 2.6.32 kernel, everything works good, and you even dont need to add "-I" to "ping" command, it seams in my kernel (3.2.0) somebody broken this feature.

Answer (score 2):

The `src` option only affects packets whose source address is chosen by the operating system. The `ping` program chooses its own source address. If you want to influence its choice, use the `-I` or `-B` options. If you want to see if your `src` option is working, make a TCP connection or send a UDP datagram.

Comment: also i do "ping 192.168.1.50 -I eth0:1", and nothing changes in tcpdump, it takes same IP

Answer (score 1):

try adding a specific route like below:

ip route add 192.168.1.50/32 dev eth0 proto static src 192.168.1.99

this should result in any traffic to 192.168.1.50 being sent with a src-ip of 192.168.1.99...instead of default 192.168.1.1